# Where does a Comparator live in a domain-driven MVC world?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, architecture, namespaces, domain-driven-design

I have a class that needs to be sortable in a couple of different ways, many of which break the `equals()` contract, so I need to have a bunch of different `Comparator` classes. The question I have is where should those classes live?

So that there is something concrete to use as an example namespace structure and to limit the question to package structure rather than file structure, lets assume the following namespaces:

```
app
  domain
    exception
    hibernatemapping
  mvc
    propertyeditor
    tags
  persistence
    hibernate
```

Domain classes live in the `domain` namespace, and related exceptions and hibernate mapping files in `exception` and `hibernatemapping` respectively. `persistence` holds DAO interfaces, with hibernate-based implementations in `hibernate`. All of the MVC controllers live in `mvc`, with specialized property editors (this is Spring MVC) in `propertyeditor` and classes that back custom tags in `tags`.

My gut says that `Comparators` should live under the `domain` namespace, perhaps in `domain.comparator`, but I'm not sure.

Where would you put them and why?

---

Update: A number of people have suggested using a general `Util` package. When going that route, would you separate out the `Util` classes by UI helpers vs. domain helpers? For example, if the domain needed to sort things for business logic reasons, but the UI needed additional sortings that the domain doesn't care about? Basically, would you tend to have a helper package per-layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, something like a util or a commons package would seem to make the most sense, though be sure you don't end up using that as a "goto" package if you don't know where to put something.

I'd also suggest looking into [package by feature](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205). In this cause, your compartor would just go with whatever corresponding feature its used with. Again, this is only a suggestion - you'll have to make the call for the best layout of your project.

Comment: +1 for package by feature. For some projects this makes more sense that the vanilla domain/dao/service/controller formula.

Comment: So then, in a package-by-feature world, the `Comparator` would go in the same package as the things is compares? eg. a `Foo` comparator would go in the `app.foo` package?

Comment: in a package-by-feature world, you would have app.myfeature that would have the model, dao, services, and other classes that make up that feature. Presumably the controllers still exist in some other package and only talk to the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with the following structure:

```
company
  appname
     model
     util
     dao
     service
     controller
```

In this type of structure a comparator would probably get dumped into the util package (if there were really a lot of comparators).

However, usually I find that comparators are used in exactly one place, and so I declare them inline where they're actually used, e.g.

```
public class SomeService {
    public void someMethod(String id) {
        List<ListType> list = dao.getSomeListById(id);
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ListType>() {
            public compare(ListType a, ListType b) {
            // ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a package called "app.util" or "app.helper".

Conceptionally speaking, in Domain Driven Design this belongs in the infrastructure layer (http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice).

Comment: Both infrastructure and util are broad. The nice thing about util is that it's /short/.

Answer (score 0):

I made a package called `comparators` which is where I store mine.